# Codeception webdriver in windows

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, codeception

I am new to codeception.I try to follow tutorial from http://codeception.com/11-20-2013/webdriver-tests-with-codeception.html. I install codeception using my composer.

```
"require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "*"
}
```

and I have codeception.Now I need Selenium server I try

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar
```

which give me error unable to access jarFile. So I used npm to install Selenium server and I have selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-jar-2.50.1.jar inside. And change my path to myproject/node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar and try run

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar
```

I see something in my screen [image]

Can anyone suggest me what I did wrong. My operating system in Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: The image show "selenium server is up and running", so what is you problem exactly ?

Comment: The problem is I cannot do nothing after. Its stop and even I cannot write.I dont know what to do after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar -role hub
help me

Thank you.